# Parsley.js in Wordpress "undefined is not a function" And EqualTo Not Working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parsley.js

I'm having issues with Parsley.js 2.0.6 in WordPress (Bones theme).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#myForm').parsley(); // "undefined is not a function'
});
```

Without making this call to parsley, required attributes still work (which is puzzling), but

```
<input type="password" id="password" required />
<input type="password" id="confirm-password" required data-parsley-equalto="#password" />
```

does not. The required part works, but I can still submit my form even if the passwords are totally different. I thought maybe this was because I was not calling parsley on the form, but calling it results in the above error. I'm out of ideas.

This issue should have been fixed: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/685

So, I really don't understand what's going on. I have other calls that work fine such as:

```
$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999'); //input masking plugin - no errors, works as expected
```

So,  I know it's not a $/jQuery variable problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ready function is wrong.

Use instead:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
    $('#myForm').parsley();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Argh! This remove the error, but now my mask plugin does not work!

Comment: Without an example this can't be answered.